# Reinstalling Built-in Windows Apps

Tags: windows, windows-11, system-restore, windows-store-app

So, a recent wifi driver update apparently broke my **Windows 11** and causes a couple of blue screens. I decided to run a **System Restore** from the windows UEFI menu. It fixed the blue screen somewhat. However, it causes another set of problem.

After running System Restore, at least Windows Terminal and Notepad is not working. It appears that the executable files are missing. Luckily, `cmd` is still exists. I tried to use `sfc /scannow` and `dism /Cleanup-Image /Restore-Health` from administrative `cmd` to no avail.

I managed to fix the issue by using **Windows Settings** and press the **Repair** button for the Notepad, but I'm not quite sure which apps are missing. Is there an efficient way apart from pressing **Repair** one-by-one to reinstall the broken Windows Apps?

Comment: SFC and DISM don’t fix non-system files like Windows Terminal. You will want to reinstall the applications from the Microsoft Store. Difficult to advise without knowing which applications don’t actually work.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, i just figured recently that Windows Terminal wasn't part of windows system stuff. its such a confusing times when ALT+X then A won't give me a command line to work with. the app which i'm aware of at least Windows Terminal and Notepad - two which i used daily. i could fix the thing using Windows Settings, but windows had a bunch of apps replacing the old stuff and its painful to press repair on each of them (which i'm doing right now).

Comment: Notepad stopped being a system application more than 4 years ago when it became a UWP

Comment: First choice would be restore from a drive image. If you don't have one, second would be the *manufacturer's* restore disk - it might be available online, if the PC did not come with one (*N.B.* - this might erase data!). Third choice would be downloading the Win 11 ISO from Microsoft, reinstalling (keeping files), and then adding in piecemeal what's missing.